# Cross-Origin Request Blocked Error After Configured Cors

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

In my Asp.net Core WebApi , I have been configured Configure method in Startup.cs file like this:

```
app.UseCors(option=>
            option.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod());
```

But when I attempt to post data to an Action method (using axios) . Bellow error occure:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'my domain' from origin 'my domain' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is related to Plesk issues. I report it and is fixed by the supporting team